# ASP:Menü: complete Menu margin?

Tags: asp.net, aspmenu

I have a ASP:Menü in vertical style.

The MainItem is only 1 Button, deisgned by a Image (no text, pure image).

The ChildItems are normal Text.

Here is a very high zoomed screenshot: http://s2.imgimg.de/uploads/UnbenanntesBild661673a8png.png

Now, beacuse of the image, the childItems look very... strange, because the ChilItems begin, where the button is not there (very hard to explain, sorry).
I want to have the child menü begins at the pixel the button beginns after the white seperator in the image.

So, I want to move the whole childItems 2-4px to the right, how I can do this?

Comment: That would be the metal-themed menu, no?

Comment: Please? Sry don't understand.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_umlaut + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_metal_%28interface%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a left rule to the style of the sub-item, similar to the following:

```
.subitem
{
    ...
    left: 1px;
    ...
}
```

You will need to figure out the exact spacing for yourself, as you have not included the actually styling for me to test with.